# Injecting JS via chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to inject some JS code via a chrome extension to a given webpage.

I'm using this method to do it:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
// TODO: add "script.js" to web_accessible_resources in manifest.json
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('script.js');
s.onload = function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

I have a few scripts that I load that way and they all work great except one. The one that's not being loaded correctly for some reason is `kbpgp.js` which is a browserified nodejs code (source here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/keybase/kbpgp/master/browser/kbpgp.js)

When I load it via the extension I can see that the actual file is being loaded as I can see it in the resources list.

If I take that code and load it via a regular html page by using `<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/keybase/kbpgp/master/browser/kbpgp.js"></script>` I can see that it exposes a method called `kbpgp` while when I try and load it via the extension that method is not available.

`manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Getting started example",
  "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://www.facebook.com/*"
      ],
      "css": [
        "css/style.css"
      ],
      "js": [
        "lib/init.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "lib/kbpgp.js",
    "lib/jquery.js",
    "lib/pgp.js"
  ]
}
```

`init.js`:

```
function loadScript(path, callback) {
  console.log('Loading', path);
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.src = chrome.extension.getURL(path);
  (document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
  console.log(s);
  setTimeout(function () {
    callback();
  }, 2000);
}

loadScript('lib/kbpgp.js', function () {
  loadScript('lib/jquery.js', function () {
    loadScript('lib/pgp.js', function () {
      console.log('PGP Extension loaded');
    });
  });
});
```

(Please ignore the very ugly implementation of my `loadScript` function).

I can use the `mytest()` function that resides in my pgp.js file but not the `kbpgp()` method that is inside the `kbpgp.js` file even though I can clearly see that kbpgp.js is loaded inside the page.

Comment: _"This method is not available"_ where? In the content script?

Comment: @Xan In my console.log on a webpage that has the extension loaded on. I can access other functions from other js files that I load via the extension, but not the `kbpgp` method for some reason.

Comment: I'm just making sure you're trying to use it from the page's context, not the content script context.

Comment: The answer, while incorrect, does raise a point - do you try to execute that _injector_ script with `"run_at"` set? Try `"document_start"`.

Comment: @Xan I've added some more information to my question, thanks

Comment: BTW, you don't normally need timeouts; `appendChild` blocks until the script is executed.

Comment: I found some inconsistencies in the order of the scripts that are being loaded. So decided to implement an ugly fix just for my poc and fix it later. seems to work.

Comment: Don't think this is an extension related problem. If you execute the kbpgp.js src in the console on facebook, it won't expose any kbpgp method. Doing so in other pages works, it's just on facebook that it doesn't for some reason..